# After I merged YouTube and Google+ I can't get the password of YouTube

Tags: youtube, google-plus, account-recovery

I just merged my YouTube account with Google+. 
I was using an app to upload my videos to my YouTube channel, now this password is rejected. I only have one password; I don't remember creating a new password for Google+.

Where can I find the new password?

Answer (score 1):

Two things happened since:

- You created probably a Google+ page, which is it's own sort of account for which you could set it's own password.
- The app you were using used YouTube's Data APIv2, which has been shut down in April 2015. The APIv3 only supports OAuth, which circumvents the entire password issue by not needing to know the password.